# Cardboard for unity top left corner of the return button how to remove?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

[image]Cardboard for unity top left corner of the return button how to remove? Do not display it, my cardboard version is 0.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done right now. I tried removing it myself, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I found that you can delete, in unity search androiddevice script, the code inside the Notes can, ios is also true